# Get the true exception class from asmx web service using MSTest

Tags: exception, asmx, mstest, assert

So I have this web service that I am testing using MS Test and I want to get the original exception class which is `InvalidOperationException`. However whenever I run my test, the exception that I get is the `FaultException` class (which is the default exception when consuming a web service). I only get the exception in the message property of the exception.

Below is the exception message that I am getting.

`System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid Entity\n   at BL.Lib.WebService.BLWebServiceImpl.UpdateIDNumber(GetUpdateIDNumberRequest idNumberRequest) in [some file]:line 369\n   at SSMWebService.Blacklist.BLWebService.BlacklistUpdateIDNumber(GetUpdateIDNumberRequest request) in [some asmx file]:line 132\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Is there a way to get the `InvalidOperationException` class from the web service?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Nope. I tried, but it will always fall back to the `FaultException`. I don't want to depend on the exception message and search the string if it has this exception class because it will be stupid.